# Combine multiple lists inside a BindingSource

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview, odp.net

I'm using a `BindingSource` to gather up some `DataGridView`s on multiple database calls.

What I want to do is combined all the `DataGridView`s in the `.List`  property of the `BindingSource` into one so I can use `DataGridView.DataSource = BindingSource`.

I've tried the following, but it only binds the collection itself and not the `.List` properties.

```
BindingSource _bindingSource = new BindingSource();
...
...
while(<doing database calls>) {
    // Populate _DataGridView with some a DB Call

    _bindingSource.Add(_DataGridView); // Add _DataGridView to the _bindingSource
}
DataGrid.Datasource = _bindingSource;
```

What I want is something like this

```
// Populate _bindingSource with the .List property/or all the items within _bindingSource 
DataGrid.Datasource = _bindingSource[0] + _bindingSource[1] + ..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataSource` is `object`.

So you will need to **know more** about the actual DS you are using; then you can  (maybe using a suitable `Cast<>`) `Concat` (or `Union`) the various enumerations.

Let's look at a simple example using `DataGridViews` that are bound to `DataTables` :

```
var twoDataSources = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).Select()
             .Concat(((DataTable)dataGridView2.DataSource).Select());

var twoDataSources = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).Select()
              .Union(((DataTable)dataGridView2.DataSource).Select());
```

The first example contains each row in each table; the seconds contains all unique rows.

If you need more help please add the actual code that creates the datasources. (Of course they would have to be field-compatible..)